# Single use skins with transmutations

Tags: guild-wars-2

If you get a drop of a single use skin. It's obviously single use to apply it to an item. But can you then transmute that item skin to other items using a transmutation stone/crystal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure can!

The skin of an item is independent from everything else. As long as you have a [transmutation crystal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Transmutation_Crystal) (if the stats are level 80) or [transmutation stone](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Transmutation_Stone) (for lower level items), you can pass the skin around from item to item ad infinitum.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can transfer skins off Soulbound items too. So if you want to move the skin to another character you can.